# Google geocode API returns location of motorway rather than postcode area supplied

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, geocode

I get the same result if I use the URL or javascript APIs.

If I pass (as an address) the location "M5" for geocoding, rather than returning the location of the M5 Postal Area (Salford, Manchester) the location returned is the centre of the M5 Motorway.

Interestingly in the old google maps (http://maps.google.co.uk) I get the same behaviour but the new google maps (same URL) returns the correct area.

Is there another way I can define the location (rather than 'address') that will be more accurate? The only other requirement is that the user may enter a town / city / county name rather than a post code so the solution needs to be flexible enough to handle this.

Comment: The geocoder (at least the javascript version) gives me Salford as the second result, are you checking all the results? `Found 25 results for M5
[ 0 ]: M5, Droitwich WR9, UK (51.5157456, -2.6464826999999786)
[ 1 ]: Salford M5, UK (53.4796425, -2.2810638999999355)`

Comment: Same with me. And using `region: 'uk'` the only result is `Salford M5, UK (53.4796425, -2.2810638999999355)`.

Comment: It seems adding the region as UK solves this problem. Strange as all the results returned were in the UK anyway but thank you for suggesting this - big help.

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for this? I've run into the same issue recently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect results returned from a partial UK postcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842474/incorrect-results-returned-from-a-partial-uk-postcode)